# How does the sumcheck protocol help solving the #SAT (circuit satisfiability) problem?

Tags: complexity-theory, satisfiability, zero-knowledge-proofs

I am going through Justin Thaler's book - https://people.cs.georgetown.edu/jthaler/ProofsArgsAndZK.pdf - "Proofs, Arguments, and Zero-Knowledge"

He presents the Sumcheck protocol & then claims on Page 41 that the interactive Sumcheck protocol helps solve the SAT problem in better than exponential time.

What Sumcheck does is

$H = \sum_{b_1 \in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace} \space \sum_{b_2 \in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace} \space ... \space \sum_{b_v \in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace} g(b_1, b_2,...,b_v)$

However, this is summing up all the total of all possible values the circuit can evaluate to. How does that give you the values which with satisfy the circuit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't solve SAT in faster than exponential time.  It solves #SAT (not SAT), and the prover still needs exponential time.

It doesn't give you the values which satisfy the circuit.  It doesn't need to.  #SAT doesn't ask you to find the values that satisfy the circuit.  It asks for a count of the number of satisfying assignments, i.e., assignments that satisfy the formula.  $g$ is chosen so that $g(b_1,\dots,b_v)$ is 1 if the assignment $b_1,\dots,b_v$ satisfies the formula, or 0 otherwise.  Summing those up counts the number of assignments where it is 1, i.e., the number of satisfying assignments.